# Pandas dataframe calculations with previous row

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, dataframe, recursion

I have the dataframe comprised of 'Linear' and 'Delta' and need to create the 'New' column.

In:

```
Linear   Delta
    30      -3  
    60     1.4
    65    -0.3
    62     4.4
    21    -2.5
    18    -0.1
    34    -3.1
    30    -1.5
    45     0.5
    55    -1.4
    43     2.8
    51     4.7
    62     2.7
```

Out:

```
Linear   Delta        New
    30      -3  
    60     1.4       60.0
    65    -0.3       59.7
    62     4.4       64.1
    21    -2.5       61.6
    18    -0.1       61.5
    34    -3.1       58.4
    30    -1.5       56.9
    45     0.5       57.4
    55    -1.4       55.0
    43     2.8       57.8
    51     4.7       51.0
    62     2.7       53.7
```

The algorithmic formula is the following one:

```
New[i] = IF( AND(Linear[i-1]<50,Linear[i]>50) ,  Linear ,  New[i-1]+Delta[i]  )
```

I tried a lot of different approaches such as `cumsum()` but never found the solution. I have spent many hours but in vain.

Comment: Can you explain how the new column is formed?

Comment: this is what I want to create, it is the output. The needed calculation is mentioned above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For this kind of recursive algorithm, consider `numba` with a manual loop. You will likely find just-in-time compilation more efficient than Pandas-based methods / iteration.

```
from numba import jit

@jit(nopython=True)
def calc_new(L, D):
    res = np.zeros(L.shape)
    res[0] = np.nan
    for i in range(1, len(res)):
        res[i] = L[i] if (L[i-1] < 50) & (L[i] > 50) else res[i-1] + D[i]
    return res

df['New'] = calc_new(df['Linear'].values, df['Delta'].values)
```

**Result**

```
print(df)

    Linear  Delta   New
0       30   -3.0   NaN
1       60    1.4  60.0
2       65   -0.3  59.7
3       62    4.4  64.1
4       21   -2.5  61.6
5       18   -0.1  61.5
6       34   -3.1  58.4
7       30   -1.5  56.9
8       45    0.5  57.4
9       55   -1.4  55.0
10      43    2.8  57.8
11      51    4.7  51.0
12      62    2.7  53.7
```

Comment: employing a loop ain't less efficient or not?

Comment: A loop isn't *in itself* less efficient. Many times `numba` is faster than vectorised Pandas. The issue is *at what level* you implement the loop. If you implement a loop on very basic C-level objects (as here) you're fine. If you implement on complex Pandas objects with larger overheads you'll see poor performance.

Comment: complex pandas objects such as? I have a (100K)X(100) ij dataset

Comment: `pd.Series` is complex. C float value is not, you really should provide more information if the solution is not efficient enough. (How fast is it now? What performance are you looking for?). This isn't about size of your dataset.

Comment: the performance is ok. your approach did not affect the performance of my code. it was more generic my last question.

Answer (score 2):

Not very nice, but working:

```
df['NEW'] = np.nan
for i, row in df.iterrows():
    if i > 0:
        m = (row['Linear'] > 50) & (df.loc[i-1, 'Linear'] < 50)
        df.loc[i, 'NEW'] = np.where(m, row['Linear'], row['Delta'] + df.loc[i-1, 'NEW'])

print (df)
    Linear  Delta   New   NEW
0       30   -3.0   NaN   NaN
1       60    1.4  60.0  60.0
2       65   -0.3  59.7  59.7
3       62    4.4  64.1  64.1
4       21   -2.5  61.6  61.6
5       18   -0.1  61.5  61.5
6       34   -3.1  58.4  58.4
7       30   -1.5  56.9  56.9
8       45    0.5  57.4  57.4
9       55   -1.4  55.0  55.0
10      43    2.8  57.8  57.8
11      51    4.7  51.0  51.0
12      62    2.7  53.7  53.7
```

Answer (score 0):

In this program I have used two temporary lists to get the work done. **"prevLinear"** list is used to get the results of Linear[i-1] results. **"tempList"** list is used to store the results of **"new"** column for future calculation purpose.
Execute the code to get the result.
Let me know if this helps.
Thank you.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


Linear = [30,60,65,62,21,18,34,30,45,55,43,51,62]
Delta = [-3,1.4,-0.3,4.4,-2.5,-0.1,-3.1,-1.5,0.5,-1.4,2.8,4.7,2.7]

df = pd.DataFrame({
            'Linear':Linear,
            'Delta':Delta
        })
prevLinear = [np.NaN if(i==0) else df.iloc[i-1,1] for i,value in enumerate(df['Linear'].values)]
df['prevLinear'] = prevLinear
tempList = []
new = []
for i,value in enumerate(df['Linear'].values):
    if(value>50 and df.iloc[i,2]<50):
        new.append(value)
        tempList.append(value)
    else:
        if(i>0):
            new.append(df.iloc[i,0]+tempList[i-1])
            tempList.append(df.iloc[i,0]+tempList[i-1])
        else:
            new.append(np.NaN)
            tempList.append(np.NaN)

new = np.round(new,1)
df['New'] = new
finalDF = df.iloc[:,[1,0,3]]
print(finalDF)
```